# Images/gifs in embeds discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Is it possible to upload an image or gif to an embed?

I have tried: `.setTitle(message.content)`, however it did not work.

My Code:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
  if(blacklist.has(message.author.id)) {
    return message.reply('You are blacklisted!');
  };

  let color = message.member.color;
  let set = db.fetch(`g_${message.guild.id}`);
  if (message.channel.id === set) {
    var serverIcon = message.guild.iconURL();
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(['331736522782932993', '267818548431290369', '303909506474049537'].includes(message.author.id) ? ' Admin ' : '')
      .setTitle(message.author.tag)
      .addField("Message:", message.content)
      .setColor('#39FF14')
      .setColor(['331736522782932993', '267818548431290369', '303909506474049537'].includes(message.author.id) ? '#ff0f00' : '#39FF14')
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
      .setFooter(`Server: ${message.guild.name} || UserID: ${message.author.id}`);
    message.delete()   
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => {
      try {
        client.channels.cache.get(db.fetch(`g_${g.id}`)).send(embed);
      } catch (e) {
        return;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fixing your code**
Firstly, I have noticed that you have set the color of the embed twice.
I suggest that you remove the one as it may cause more errors in the future.
If you need help doing so please consider replacing your current code with the code I have attached below:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
  if(blacklist.has(message.author.id)) {
    return message.reply('You are blacklisted!');
  };

  let color = message.member.color;
  let set = db.fetch(`g_${message.guild.id}`);
  if (message.channel.id === set) {
    var serverIcon = message.guild.iconURL();
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(['331736522782932993', '267818548431290369', '303909506474049537'].includes(message.author.id) ? ' Admin ' : '')
      .setTitle(message.author.tag)
      .addField("Message:", message.content)
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
      .setFooter(`Server: ${message.guild.name} || UserID: ${message.author.id}`)
      if (['331736522782932993', '267818548431290369', '303909506474049537'].includes(message.author.id)) {
          embed.setColor('#ff0f00')
      } else {
          embed.setColor('#39FF14')
      }
    message.delete()
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => {
      try {
        client.channels.cache.get(db.fetch(`g_${g.id}`)).send(embed);
      } catch (e) {
        return;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**Adding an image to your embed**
To add an image to your embed you will do the following:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
  if(blacklist.has(message.author.id)) {
    return message.reply('You are blacklisted!');
  };

  let color = message.member.color;
  let set = db.fetch(`g_${message.guild.id}`);
  if (message.channel.id === set) {
    var serverIcon = message.guild.iconURL();
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() //defining embed
      .setAuthor(['331736522782932993', '267818548431290369', '303909506474049537'].includes(message.author.id) ? ' Admin ' : '') //adding an author to the embed
      .setTitle(message.author.tag) //setting a title for the embed
      .setDescription(`**Message:**\n${message.content}`) //setting the description for the embed
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL()) //adding a thumbnail
      .setImage('ImageURL') //adding a image
      .setFooter(`Server: ${message.guild.name} || UserID: ${message.author.id}`) //adding a footer
      if (['331736522782932993', '267818548431290369', '303909506474049537'].includes(message.author.id)) { //checks if the authors ID is in the table
          embed.setColor('#ff0f00') //if the author is in the table, the embed color will set to red
      } else {
          embed.setColor('#39FF14') //if the author is not in the table, the embed color will set to green
      }
    message.delete() //deleting the message that was sent
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => {
     try {
       client.channels.cache.get(db.fetch(`g_${g.id}`)).send(embed); //sending the embed
     } catch {
       return;
     }
    });
  }
});
```